# Raspberry Pi List of Compatible Receivers

Tags: raspberry-pi

I'm looking for a list of receivers that are compatible with the Raspberry Pi. I am trying to get an idea of all the different methods of communication that the Raspberry Pi is currently able to pick up. So far, I know that there is at least one Pi-compatible instance of each of the following receivers on the market:

- RF (Radio Frequency) receiver
- IR (Infrared) receiver
- Bluetooth receiver

Internet searches have yielded nothing so far. Can anyone add to this list? I'd like to know if there's a receiver that can pick up a magnetic field change (like the iPhone's Hall sensor) or a receiver that can pick up a frequency change, but I'm looking for anything to add to this list.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

http://elinux.org/RPi_VerifiedPeripherals

This is a list of all verified devices for the pi I found.